# Is this a 2 or 4 CPU Configuration?

Tags: central-processing-unit, socket

I'm looking at this server configuration (I'm reviewing a customer's potential order for a server for our software) and I'm trying to understand what kind of CPUs would come on the server.

**HP SB Gen8 DL380P E5-2670**

Looking this up I see some sites list this as **2-way - 2 x Xeon E5-2670 / 2.6 GHz**

Since the E5-2670 is the CPU I'm assuming this is 2 CPUs (sockets?), however I don't understand what *2-way - 2 x Xeon...* implies.

I understand that each CPU will have 8 cores

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server is "2-way" because it contains two Xeon E5-2670's. These are 8-core CPUs with hyper-threading, so the server would have 16 physical cores and 32 virtual cores.

I believe the DL380p always has two sockets.

Comment: +1 Even though you're missing the [Quickspecs](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14212_div/14212_div.HTML)

Comment: Also see:  http://ark.intel.com/products/64595

Answer (score 2):

It is a 8-core CPU that can either be used alone or, if you got a mainboard with two sockets, it can be used with another CPU of the same type.

So its one E5-2670 CPU or two E5-2670 CPUs in a system.

Preferably trust Intels specifications: [look here](http://ark.intel.com/products/64595/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2670-20M-Cache-2_60-GHz-8_00-GTs-Intel-QPI?q=E5-2670)

The option to interpret is "Scalability 2S Only". It means that the CPU is useable for a  mainboard with up to 2 Sockets.

If it is the **HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8 E5-2670 2P** : It has 2 Processors.